# POI not found with geocoding API

Tags: mapbox, geocoding, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to use the MapBox Geocoding API and for it I tried to translate "Centre Hospitalier Régional d'Orléans" (that is an Hospital in France, Orléans) into Lng/Lat coordinates.

When I display a MapBox Map, I can see the POI: [image: CHRO POI on Mapbox]

And when I click it in MapBox Studio, it is well recognized as a Point Of Interest (POI) (`poi-label`):[image: POI]

But when I try to find it using the Geocoding API, I don't find it.
Here is the request I run: 
`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Centre%20Hospitalier.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWF0dGZpY2tlIiwiYSI6ImNqNnM2YmFoNzAwcTMzM214NTB1NHdwbnoifQ.Or19S7KmYPHW8YjRz82v6g&cachebuster=1547469044480&autocomplete=true&country=fr&proximity=1.909251%2C47.902964`

Is it normal ? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug ?

Answer (score 4):

The data behind the maps and the geocoder aren't necessarily the same, so it's likely this Hospital is showing up on the map from OpenStreetMap, but isn't in the data being used for the geocoder.

Some information about data sources is at https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/

You can report feedback about this at https://apps.mapbox.com/feedback/ mentioning its a geocoding issue.

Comment: Ok, I thought that the POI displayed on the map where extracted from the same source as the Geocoding API.
I contacted Mapbox on twitter and they recommended me to add the POI on Foursquare that is their source: https://twitter.com/mzdraper/status/1084831767159201795